# Obj-C, Potential leak of an object allocated on line, warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I've declared the following variable as an instance variable and am using it in my m file, however I've getting a warning.

```
TransparentToolbar *tools;
```

Potential leak of an object allocated on line ...

I' have tried creating a property for it, for example..

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) TransparentToolbar *tools;
```

And synthesize'ing and releasing it, but my view crashes at the end of dealloc.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT same warning on pickerSortingDataCurrent ...

```
h
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, 
    UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, 
    UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {

    TransparentToolbar *tools;

    NSArray *pickerSortingDataCurrent;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) TransparentToolbar *tools;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pickerSortingDataCurrent;

m
@synthesize pickerSortingDataCurrent;
@synthesize tools;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tools = [[[TransparentToolbar alloc] 
           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44.01)] autorelease];
    tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    self.pickerSortingDataCurrent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
      @"Next Date Ascending", 
      @"Next Date Descending", nil];     // removed some items here
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [tools release];
    [pickerSortingDataCurrent release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Ahhhh I have autorelease.... but that doesn't solve the pickerSortingDataCurrent ...

EDIT...

```
#import "TransparentToolbar.h"

@implementation TransparentToolbar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // do nothing in here
}

- (void) applyTranslucentBackground
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.opaque = NO;
    self.translucent = YES;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    [self applyTranslucentBackground];
    return self;
}

// Override initWithFrame.
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self applyTranslucentBackground];
    return self;
}

@end
```

FURTHER EDIT
[image]

Comment: It's hard to say without code.

Comment: Could you include your `dealloc`code?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, with a interface data array I populate in viewDidLoad, see edit above.

Comment: the more info you provide, the easier it is for us to help you. e.g. how do use your property? dealloc defined in TransparentToolbar etc.

Comment: @Anders K, see TransparentToolbar class above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define `@property` then generally any time you access the ivar in your class you use the getter/setter whether that be dot notation or standard method call.

**Dot notation**

```
id localyMyVar = self.myVar;
self.myVar = @"A string";
```

**Standard method call**

```
id localMyVar = [self myVar];
[self setMyVar:@"A string"];
```

If you always explicitly use these getters and setters then you pretty much do not need to call release anywhere in your code apart from `dealloc` or an overridden `setMyVar:` method. Doing it this way allows memory management to occur in limited places. If you start releasing and retaining yourself then things can be a bit complicated when you first start out.

**UPDATE**

@bbum gives you the answer but I think you would benefit from being more consistant in your coding as well.

For example before the offending line you are assigning directly to an ivar without using the setter. Be consistant and use the setter/getter that you took the time to synthesize. I would rewrite

```
tools = [[[TransparentToolbar alloc] 
       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44.01)] autorelease];
tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

to

```
TransparentToolbar *tmpTools = [[TransparentToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44.01)];
tmpTools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
self.tools = tmpTools;
[tmpTools release]; tmpTools = nil;
```

Your `init` methods are not really following the guidelines either you should be checking that `self` is actually set, so it should look something similar to:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self applyTranslucentBackground];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The memory leak you are seeing here:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.tools];
```

is because you look at the docs for [UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) you will see that `rightBarButtonItem` is declared as `retain`

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem
```

Therefore the call `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` will take a +1 retain on the object you pass in and then you are alloc/initing which is another +1 retain. The `UINavigationItem` will release it's retain when it is dealloc'd but there will still be your original retain hanging around.

The fix:

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.tools];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
[rightBarButtonItem release]; rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: I'm still getting a warning caused by this line `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.tools];`

Answer (score 1):

```
self.pickerSortingDataCurrent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
  @"Next Date Ascending", 
  @"Next Date Descending", nil];     // removed some items here
```

+1 retain count for the +alloc, +1 retain count for the assignment to the `retain` `@property`.

Rewrite it as:

```
NSArray *labels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
  @"Next Date Ascending", 
  @"Next Date Descending", nil];
self.pickerSortingDataCurrent = labels;
[labels release];
```

(Or you could use `autorelease`)

Comment: That still gives me a warning from the line before see above comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a property with `retain`, you must set it to nil in your dealloc method.

i.e.

```
@interface DMFakeyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bogusString;

@end

@implementation DMFakeyClass

-(void)dealloc {
    self.bogusString = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

That's pretty much all you have to do to have a successful memory management strategy. When you use this property, always use the getter/setter (`self.bogusString = [NSString stringWithString:@"bogus"];`) and make sure you've autoreleased or released anything you alloc (`self.bogusString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"bogus2"] autorelease];`). Follow that pattern and you shouldn't have any issues.